# VisualCollection to Visual HitTest invisible?

Tags: c#, wpf, visualtreehelper

I am working with VisualCollection, Visual and HitTest in WPF and encountered a problem.

I tried to make a custom visual drawing as follows:

```
public class MyDrawing : Visual
{
    VisualCollection vc;

    public MyDrawing()
    {
        vc = new VisualCollection(this);
    }

     // ...
     DrawingVisual rectangle = new DrawingVisual();
     // ...

     vc.Add(rectangle);
}

public class DrawingArea : FrameworkElement
{
    VisualCollection vc;

    public DrawingArea()
    {
        vc = new VisualCollection(this);

        MyDrawing md1 = new MyDrawing();

        vc.Add(md1);
    }    

    public void TryToHit(Point p)
    {      
        HitTestResult result = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(this, p);
    }    
}
```

Then I found that the result is rectangle but not md1.

How could I make MyDrawing become the basic Visual element so that the VisualTreeHelper would not further do HitTest inside?

Thank you very much.

Comment: See [Hit Testing in the Visual Layer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752097.aspx), especially the section [Using a Hit Test Filter Callback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752097.aspx#using_a_hit_test_filter_callback).

Comment: Add a specific example of what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Drawingvisual. Try the below one.

```
  public class NoHitTestDrawingVisual : DrawingVisual
    {

        protected override GeometryHitTestResult HitTestCore(GeometryHitTestParameters hitTestParameters)
        {
            return null;
        }

        protected override HitTestResult HitTestCore(PointHitTestParameters hitTestParameters)
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: I'm afraid this won't work unless the parent visual (`MyDrawing md1` here) has itself rendered (and hence hit-testable) content.